# How to paginate filtered results with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, filter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have a list of customers saved in a firestore collection built like this:

- customer_1234

  - name: customer1
  - category: category1
  - city: city1
  - country: country1
- customer_5678

  - name: customer2
  - category: category2
  - city: city2
  - country: country2
- other customers...

Now, i want to create a customers archive page with some filters (by name, by category, by city, by country).

I would like to show results 20 at a time with an infinite scroll system.

For example I could request all the customers of a certain city and then I could add a second filter (by category) and mix them together.

What is the best way to build this system?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to paginate your query using the technique described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query).

For example, with your last example:

```
var first = db.collection("customers")
        .where('city', '==', 'city1')
        .where('category', '==', 'category1')
        .limit("20");

return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 20 customers.
  var next = db.collection("customers")
        .where('city', '==', 'city1')
        .where('category', '==', 'category1')
        .startAfter(lastVisible)
        .limit("20");

});
```

Comment: is it necessary to create an index to use multiple times .where()? Cansole says: "The query requires an index."

Comment: Normally with the error message you shoudl have an URL that will create the index.